# necesito mandar mi check box marcados en un array y enviarlos a un destino.php

Tags: ajax

/*esta funcion me trae todos los checkbox marcados con su numero id de alumnos de la base de datos y me lo muestra en un alert.

Quisiera guardar en la variablearray los checkbox que me trae el alert */

```
function contar(){
  $('#tblRegistros').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {   

  alert($(this).val());
variablearray=  

});



   $.ajax({

      type:"POST",
      url:"vistas/recibe.php",
      data:"codigos=" + variablearray, 
      success:function(r){
        $('#informerecibido').html(r);
      }     
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu función puedes crear un array y mandarla por medio de un objeto

```
function contar(){

    var variablearray = []; 
     $('#tblRegistros').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {   
variablararray.push($(this).val());
});

var data = {
    codigos: variablearray
};

$.ajax({

      type:"POST",
      url:"vistas/recibe.php",
      data: data,
      success:function(r){
        $('#informerecibido').html(r);
      }     
    }); 
}
```